# What is the point of template specification declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

I've seen people who have a template class declaration in a header file and the implementation in a .cpp file, and in the .cpp file they implement the methods, and then it appears they declare some template specifications for those functions, e.g., the below code does it:

Class declaration file:

```
template<int dim = 2>
struct custom_class {
  void apply(int i, int j, int k);
}
```

Implementation file:

```
template <int dim>
void custom_class<dim>::apply() {
  // implement apply
}

// what is the point of the below two lines?
template void custom_class<2>::apply(int i, int j, int k);
template void custom_class<3>::apply(int i, int j, int k);
```

I am wondering what is the point of the last 2 lines of this code? What does it do?

Comment: The shown lines are incorrect. You seem to be missing a `template` keyword before each of them. With that, these become _explicit instantiations_, not _specializations_.

Comment: 1. Templates can be _instantiated_.  2.  The two lines you ask about are _explicitly instantiating_  a template.